# Display multiple taxonomies in a function

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am trying to edit a plugin that allows 1 taxonomy to be associated with a custom post type on import of data. I need it to have several custom taxonomies. Here is the original function:

```
/**
 * Initialize the class and set its properties.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function __construct() {

    $this->event_posttype = 'facebook_events';
    $this->taxonomy = 'classification';
    $this->tag_taxonomy = 'facebook_tag';

}
```

I have tried the following, which doesn't work.

```
    /**
 * Initialize the class and set its properties.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function __construct() {

    $this->event_posttype = 'facebook_events';
    $this->taxonomy = array(
                     'top_level_homepage_categories',
                     'another_category',
                     'subcategory',
                     'age_range',
                     'classification');
    $this->tag_taxonomy = 'facebook_tag';

}
```

input gratefully received, 1st time posting, hope I have done it right...

Comment: Wherever `$this->taxonomy` is used later on, possibly multiple times, the plugin likely doesn't account for there being multiple taxonomies. You would likely need to modify every instance of that property being used.

Comment: thanks, I have found 2 instances, and by changing both $this->taxonomy = 'classification'; to $this->taxonomy = 'something-else'; I can change taxonomy used. I need to get all taxonomies displayed.

Comment: It’s not an answer, but it’s worth mentioning, I guess... You should never modify plugins, themes or WP core. What will you do, when there will be new version of that plugin? ;)

Comment: I hear what you are saying, I'll make a copy and keep it documented. I'll change name so it won't update.